# NavigationView Menu icon Overlapping the menu items UWP

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, uwp, windows-10-universal, uwp-xaml

I have a problem with NavigationView in UWP, the control generate the hamburger menu but I have the Menu button that overlap the first item under it, at the same time I have an empty space above it.

I use last SDK 16299 Fall Creators Update, that is the minimum version for NavigationView support

This is how appear the application-

[image: screenshot]

The XAML code is this:

```
<NavigationView CompactModeThresholdWidth="300" ExpandedModeThresholdWidth="1920" x:Name="NavView" ItemInvoked="NavView_ItemInvoked" SelectionChanged="NavView_SelectionChanged" Loaded="NavView_Loaded" Canvas.ZIndex="0">
    <NavigationView.MenuItems>
        <NavigationViewItem x:Uid="HomeNavItem" Content="Home" Tag="Home">
            <!-- Margin="0,48,0,0" -->
            <NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                <FontIcon Glyph="&#xE10F;"/>
            </NavigationViewItem.Icon>
        </NavigationViewItem>
        <NavigationViewItem x:Uid="DatiNavItem" Content="Dati" Tag="Dati">
            <NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                <FontIcon Glyph="&#xE8F1;"/>
            </NavigationViewItem.Icon>
        </NavigationViewItem>
        <NavigationViewItem x:Uid="GraficiNavItem" Content="Grafici" Tag="Grafici">
            <NavigationViewItem.Icon>
                <FontIcon Glyph="&#xE877;"/>
            </NavigationViewItem.Icon>
        </NavigationViewItem>
    </NavigationView.MenuItems>
    <NavigationView.PaneFooter>
        <NavigationViewItem x:Uid="LoginItem" Tag="Login">
            <FontIcon Glyph="&#xE77B;"/>
        </NavigationViewItem>
    </NavigationView.PaneFooter>
</NavigationView>
```

If I add `Margin="0,48,0,0"` to the first Item under menu icon i resolve the overlap but not the empty space.

I do not have any idea how to resolve the problem

Comment: That is certainly very unusual. Are you setting some default styles on buttons? From the image it seems that the NavigationView has a acrylic background as well, so haven't you accidentally applied some kind of style that moves the hamburger down? I have tried your XAML in an empty project and it works normally

Comment: Every empty project that I create have this problem when i use NavigationView maybe is a problem of my installation of Visual Studio

Comment: Yes, I would try to do a repair then... Don't you have a insider preview build of Windows 10?

Comment: Yes, maybe is the Insider Preview, but I didn't seem to have seen this bug in the changelog. Thanks for help

Comment: I have created a simple sample with your code, it works well in my side. have you tried to deploy the solution in other device?

Comment: Yes, I distributed the solution on another device with an official version of Windows 10 and it works all right, I think it's a parse problem of the XAML in my Insider Build

Comment: I have the exact same issue on my Insider build, hope this gets fixed soon.

Comment: Yes, this is an insider build problem, I think new OS installation is the only way